# Method parameter with `class` elaborated type specifier

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to understand the following piece of code:

```
lock_server::lock_server(class rsm *_rsm)
{
//code
}
```

I know that this is the constructor for the class, but I don't understand its argument.
I'm guessing that this is a pointer (with name _rsm) that points to a *class*? Does that make sense? Where can I find documentation about this?

Comment: it's just a pointer, only this time to a class rms. The class keyword is to enlighten the reader, but can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `class` before the term `rsm` is not necessary in C++ (unlike in C where you must specify the word `struct`).

However that doesn't mean it is forbidden and whoever wrote that felt it was good style, albeit it's intuitive that `rsm` is a type of some sort (not necessarily a class, could be a typedef to a class)

The purpose of that constructor is to construct an object of type `lock_server` with a pointer to a modifiable `rsm` object. My guess is that `rsm` has some kind of `lock` method which will be called from the constructor, and an `unlock` method which will be called from the destructor.

The purpose of the `lock_server` class is to implement what is called RAII: a stupid acronym but in real life it means automated resource management - when the object leaves scope the destructor kicks in which releases the resource it is holding, in this case a lock to the `rsm` object.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Your guess is a bit off (lock_server is actually a RPC-exposed map of mutexes), but, reading up on it, RAII seems to be an interesting technique

Answer (score 5):

class or struct keywords are optional in C++ when specifying a type, and usually omitted.

That is, the following functions have an equivalent signature:

```
class mytype { ... };

void f(mytype* data);       // compiler "understands" that mytype is a class
void g(class mytype* data);
```

Comment: It is known as an *elaborated type specifier*.

Answer (score 2):

If the class in question wasn't declared beforehand, you have to include the word `class`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer, to an object of class `rsm`.

The keyword `class` is optional, as long as the class `rsm` was previously defined/declared.

However, if the class wasn't previously declared at the point in the source, the `class` keyword is necessary. In this case the `rsm` declared as an incomplete class type.